# Entity framework: Cascading foreign key cannot be created where the referencing column is an identity column. Could not create constraint or index

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am having an issue trying to create a one to one relationship to a pivot table. These are my models

```
    public class StudentCourse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExamResult
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        public int TotalMarks { get; set; }
        public virtual StudentCourse StudentCourse { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the model builder config where I have defined my many to many relationship between Student and Course

```
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.StudentId, sc.CourseId });
                modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().HasAlternateKey(e => e.Id);
                modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                    .HasOne(sc => sc.Student)
                    .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
                    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.StudentId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                    .HasOne(sc => sc.Course)
                    .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
                    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CourseId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            }
```

And this is the error message I am getting when I run the migrations

```
Failed executing DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [StudentCourses] (
    [StudentId] int NOT NULL,
    [CourseId] int NOT NULL,
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentCourses] PRIMARY KEY ([StudentId], [CourseId]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_StudentCourses_Id] UNIQUE ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourses_Courses_CourseId] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [Courses] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourses_ExamResults_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [ExamResults] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourses_Students_StudentId] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [Students] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Cascading foreign key 'FK_StudentCourses_ExamResults_Id' cannot be created where the referencing column 'StudentCourses.Id' is an identity column.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Essentially I am trying to point to a StudentCourse record from the ExamResult table, but for some reason it's failing. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an EF Core issue/bug which seems to be fixed in EF Core 3.0. The alternate key `Id` of `StudentCourse` somehow is confusing the pre EF Core 3.0 relationship conventions and instead of intended many-to-one relationship from `ExamResult` to `StudentCourse` it wrongly assumes one-to-one relationship with `ExamResult` being the principal and  `StudentCourse` being the dependent, hence the lack of FK in `ExamResult` and wrong FK in `StudentCourse`.

The solution is to explicitly configure the desired relationship via fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExamResult>()
    .HasOne(e => e.StudentCourse)
    .WithMany();
```

Note that this will create an optional composite FK in `ExamResult` referencing the composite PK of `StudentCourse`. If you want to relate the by the alternate key of the `StudentCourse`, you should configure that with `HasPrincipalKey` API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExamResult>()
    .HasOne(e => e.StudentCourse)
    .WithMany()
    .HasPrincipalKey(sc => sc.Id);
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you so much, this issue has been driving me crazy for the past couple days and I'm glad to know it was a bug with EF Core